# MSTest - keep TestResult artifacts even on success

Tags: visual-studio-2015, mstest

Microsoft have changed default mstest's behavior of TestResult management in VS2015 ([MSTest is removing Test Results when VS2013 is running as Administrator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21811542/mstest-is-removing-test-results-when-vs2013-is-running-as-administrator)). I'm comparing to VS2010 where TestResults were stored independently of test run result.

I want to be able to see TestResults artifacts even on successful runs.
How can I achieve this?